# Need to know a function that loads on the DIV only and Not Body Onload

Tags: javascript, html, css

could someone please help me here.
I need the code to load on the DIV only and NOT on body onload. How can I do this?

```html
<div id="typingtext"><h1>New Ways To Move People</h1></div>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
var text = "New Ways To Move People !";
var charArray = text.split("");
var timer;

function Loop() {
if (charArray.length > 0) {
 document.getElementById("typingtext").innerHTML += charArray.shift();
 
} else {
 clearTimeout(timer);
  return false;
}
 
 
 timer = setTimeout('Loop()', 70);
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Jesse , sorry but you did not get it?

Comment: "". I need the code to load on the DIV only and NOT on body "" -- This needs to be explained a lot better

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87kzz4pg/) - Is this what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py ... Yes awesome thanks so much

Comment: @chipChocolate.py -- gah, i was too focused on the oddly stated question than the code